# Inheriting Python class methods?

Tags: python, inheritance, static-methods

Still don't undertstand Python inheritance, I feel... thanks for tips!

I want a subclass's instance to execute the superclass's class method. Tried this:

```
class SuperClass()
  @classmethod
  def aClassMethod(cls)
    pass

class SubClass(SuperClass)
  def aMethod(self)
    self.__class__.aClassMethod()

instance = SubClass()
instance.aMethod()
```

But Python tells me that "SubClass" does not have attribute "aClassMethod". Yes, sure, I know, but how can I make the superclass's class method accessible to the subclass instance?

Comment: Show us code that actually runs and actually demonstrates the problem when run. This code doesn't even compile, and if you fix the syntax errors, [the problem you describe doesn't appear](http://ideone.com/y6VWoE).

Comment: Please don't re-type your program. Please copy-paste your exact code into your question. See [mcve] for more information about creating sample programs.

Answer (score 1):

> how can I make the superclass's class method accessible to the subclass instance?

You don't have to do anything extraordinary. The superclass's methods, including its class methods, are all available to the subclass.

Consider a version of your program:

```
class SuperClass():
  @classmethod
  def aClassMethod(cls):
    print (cls.__name__)

class SubClass(SuperClass):
  def aMethod(self):
    # Just call the super class's class method as if it were
    # in your subclass:
    self.aClassMethod()


SubClass().aMethod()
SubClass().aClassMethod()
SubClass.aClassMethod()

SuperClass().aClassMethod()
SuperClass.aClassMethod()
```

As you can see, the class method is callable as if it were a regular method of both the superclass and the subclass. Additionally, it is callable using the class names themselves, with no instances required.

Result:

```
SubClass
SubClass
SubClass
SuperClass
SuperClass
```

Comment: But since `aClassMethod` is a class method, `self.__class__.aClassMethod` also works.